# Using Regex to find certain string (API Key)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I wanted to use a regular expressions to find if the API key exists or not.

I tried `preg_match`

```
^[a-f0-9]{32}$
```

I have this HTML code as a string.

`{"page_data":"<div class=\"row\"> <div class=\"col-md-6\"> <div class=\"card\"> <div class=\"card-header\"><h5>Affiliate API<\/h5><\/div> <div class=\"card-body\" style=\"padding:0px;\"> <table class=\"table\"> <thead> <\/thead> <tbody> <tr><td>User ID<\/td> <td>372061<\/td><\/td><td><\/tr> <tr><td>MID<\/td> <td>5132<\/td><\/td><td><\/tr> <tr><td>API Key<\/td> <td id=\"api_results\"> fbb5e3abe388cab9ef652916fe124316 <\/td><td> <span class=\"badge badge-pill badge-secondary\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\" onclick=\"api_update('create')\">Generate<\/span> <span class=\"badge badge-pill badge-danger\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\" onclick=\"api_update('disable')\">Disable<\/span><\/td><\/tr> <tr><td>API Domain<\/td><\/tr> <\/tbody> <\/table> <\/div> <\/div> <div class=\"card\"> <div class=\"card-header\"><h5>API Guide<\/h5><\/div> <div class=\"card-body\"><\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> ","page_js_register":"function api_update(t){ if(t=='create'){ var r = confirm(\"Are you sure to Create New API\"); }else{ var r = confirm(\"Are you sure to Disable API\"); } if (r == true) { $.ajax({type: \"POST\", url: \"_get?type=api_update&t=\"+t, data: '', success: function(result){ if(result.api_key){ document.getElementById(\"api_results\").innerHTML = result.api_key; } alert_c(result.txt,result.type,''); }}); } } ","title":"API"}`

Comment: You are [anchoring](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the pattern to `^` start and `$` end. Guess you want to use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the info into an html element and then it's a lot easier to find what you 're looking for.

```js
const input = `{"page_data":"<div class=\\"row\\"> <div class=\\"col-md-6\\"> <div class=\\"card\\"> <div class=\\"card-header\\"><h5>Affiliate API<\/h5><\/div> <div class=\\"card-body\\" style=\\"padding:0px;\\"> <table class=\\"table\\"> <thead> <\/thead> <tbody> <tr><td>User ID<\/td> <td>372061<\/td><\/td><td><\/tr> <tr><td>MID<\/td> <td>5132<\/td><\/td><td><\/tr> <tr><td>API Key<\/td> <td id=\\"api_results\\"> fbb5e3abe388cab9ef652916fe124316 <\/td><td> <span class=\\"badge badge-pill badge-secondary\\" style=\\"cursor: pointer;\\" onclick=\\"api_update('create')\\">Generate<\/span> <span class=\\"badge badge-pill badge-danger\\" style=\\"cursor: pointer;\\" onclick=\\"api_update('disable')\\">Disable<\/span><\/td><\/tr> <tr><td>API Domain<\/td><\/tr> <\/tbody> <\/table> <\/div> <\/div> <div class=\\"card\\"> <div class=\\"card-header\\"><h5>API Guide<\/h5><\/div> <div class=\\"card-body\\"><\/div> <\/div> <\/div> <\/div> ", "page_js_register":"function api_update(t){ if(t=='create'){ var r = confirm(\\"Are you sure to Create New API\\"); }else{ var r = confirm(\\"Are you sure to Disable API\\"); } if (r == true) { $.ajax({type: \\"POST\\", url: \\"_get?type=api_update&t=\\"+t, data: '', success: function(result){ if(result.api_key){ document.getElementById(\\"api_results\\").innerHTML = result.api_key; } alert_c(result.txt,result.type,''); }}); } } ", "title":"API"}`;

const obj = JSON.parse(input);

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = obj.page_data;

const result = div.querySelector('#api_results');

if(result != null)
{
  console.log(result.innerHTML.trim().match(/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/));
}
```